# SQL Server nested return codes

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to pass a return code up through nested procedures. The base procedure accepts several parameters and sets a return code. I'm writing a wrapper which builds up the call to the base procedure and executes it. I want the wrapper to have access to the return code from the base procedure. I've tried EXEC (@CMD) & SP_EXECUTESQL but can't seem to get the return code back. I don't really want to alter the base procedure in any way if I can help it. This is basically a wrapper for Ola Hallengrens backup which reads the parameters from a table, which I know others have implemented so someone should have a solution.

Comment: Why not use output parameters instead of return codes? Then you aren't stuck using the int datatype and you have total control over everything.

Comment: I didn't really want to make changes to the base procedure unless I have to. As I said, it's a wrapper for Ola Hallengrens databasebackup procedure so it would be nice not to have to edit it for each release.

Comment: So trying to wildly guess based on a vague explanation and comments are you calling this with dynamic sql and building a new dynamic sql string for each database? If that is the case you will have to use parameterized dynamic sql and then you can get the values back. Seems like a lot of effort for little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the return value of a stored procedure in a variable. You can then use those variables however you like (such as passing them upstream using output variables or setting them in the `session_context()`)

```
create proc dbo.test
as
return 1

declare @retval int
exec  @retval = dbo.test 

select @retval
```

Comment: I'm building up a command to execute, which is why I said EXEC (@CMD), when execing a string, @RETVAL = (@CMD) is invalid syntax.

Comment: Perhaps I misconstrued you then. You said you had nested stored procedures. Executing dynamic SQL is not a nested procedure call, so I thought maybe you were trying to employ dynamic SQL to get your return values.